Why aren't the iptables `pkts` and `bytes` count getting updated for Docker Containers, on receiving tcp packets?
I'm currently running NixOS-23.11, without any special configuration for docker, just the default install from nixpkgs.
I have the following Dockerfile definition:
FROM alpine:latest
COPY ./index.html /index.html
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip
CMD ["python3",  "-m", "http.server", "8080", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

I'm trying to trace the route of my requests:
curl localhost:80
curl localhost:8080

The docker image is built and ran with the following commands:
docker build -t test .
docker run -p 80:8080 test &
docker run -p 8080:8080 test &

My requests can reach my docker container without any issues, with the following logs on the servers:
172.17.0.1 - - [08/May/2024 08:48:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.0.1 - - [08/May/2024 08:49:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

I took a look at the iptables dump for DOCKER:

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:8080

And for the DNAT:
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 344 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2848 packets, 241K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2848 packets, 241K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      !br-ba1da9a55510  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  6    --  *      *       172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 MASQUERADE  6    --  *      *       172.17.0.3           172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:8080

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  br-ba1da9a55510 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DNAT       6    --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:172.17.0.2:8080
    0     0 DNAT       6    --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080 to:172.17.0.3:8080

Even though there have been several requests made, it seems that the pkts and bytes count do not change.
But I do see other Chains updating instead, when I make these requests:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
13652 6032K nixos-fw   0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           


Chain nixos-fw-accept (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
13652 6032K ACCEPT     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Why are the NAT tables for Docker not being hit? Is it a quirk of NixOS? Or is this expected behaviour due to some internal behaviour of Docker?

Do you see different behavior if you connect from somewhere other than localhost?
